# Erlang mnesia equivalent of "select * from Tb"

Tags: select, erlang, mnesia

I'm a total erlang noob and I just want to see what's in a particular table I have. I want to just "select *" from a particular table to start with. The examples I'm seeing, such as the [official documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#select-2), all have column restrictions which I don't really want. I don't really know how to form the MatchHead or Guard to match anything (aka "*").

A very simple primer on how to just get everything out of a table would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you can use `qlc`:

```erlang
F = fun() ->
            Q = qlc:q([R || R <- mnesia:table(foo)]),
            qlc:e(Q)
    end,
mnesia:transaction(F).
```

Comment: I love the simplicity but I am getting an error `** exception error: no match of right hand side value #Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>`. I have replaced `foo` with a real table of course. I don't understand what the error message is telling me :(

Comment: Do you try it in the shell? You have already binded a value to variable `F`. Enter `f(F).` to the shell first.

Comment: Yup, restarted the shell and it works like a champ. I didn't know that `F = ...` would not replace F. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is probably [mnesia:dirty_match_object](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#dirty_match_object-1):

```
mnesia:dirty_match_object(foo, #foo{_ = '_'}).
```

That is, match everything in the table `foo` that is a `foo` record, regardless of the values of the fields (every field is `'_'`, i.e. wildcard).  Note that since it uses record construction syntax, it will only work in a module where you have included the record definition, or in the shell after evaluating `rr(my_module)` to make the record definition available.

(I expected `mnesia:dirty_match_object(foo, '_')` to work, but that fails with a `bad_type` error.)

---

To do it with `select`, call it like this:

```
mnesia:dirty_select(foo, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]).
```

Here, `MatchHead` is `_`, i.e. match anything. The guards are `[]`, an empty list, i.e. no extra limitations.  The result spec is `['$_']`, i.e. return the entire record.  For more information about match specs, see the [match specifications chapter of the ERTS user guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html).

---

If an expression is too deep and gets printed with `...` in the shell, you can ask the shell to print the entire thing by evaluating `rp(EXPRESSION)`.  `EXPRESSION` can either be the function call once again, or `v(-1)` for the value returned by the previous expression, or `v(42)` for the value returned by the expression preceded by the shell prompt `42>`.

Comment: I get an error `* 1: record muc_room undefined`. If I do `mnesia:system_info(tables).` then `muc_room` is in the list.

Comment: the dirty_select works :) It does abbreviate some of the data with `...` is there a way to maybe dump the results to a file? Or prevent the abbreviation? Also, thank you for the description. Why is there a `$` in the result spec but not in the match spec?

Comment: See http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html for information about `$`.

Comment: Thanks, the erlang `mnesia:select` documentation mentioned the erts match spec but had no link, I had trouble finding it.

Comment: I updated the answer and added details about record definitions and printing terms in full.